# How to best create sorted sets with Redis

Tags: sorting, caching, redis, nosql

I'm still a bit lost when it comes to Sorted Sets and how to best construct them.  Currently I have a simple set of activity on my site.  Normally it will display things like User Followed, User liked, User Post etc.  The JSON looks something like...

```
id: 2808697,
activity_type: "created_follower",
description: "Bob followed this profile",
body: null,
user: "Bob",
user_id: 99384,
user_profile_id: 233007,
user_channel_id: 2165811,
user_cube_url: "bob-anerson",
user_action: "followed this profile",
buddy: "http://s3.amazonaws.com/stuff/ju-logo.jpg",
affected: "Bill Anerson is following Jon Denver.",
created_at: "2014-06-24T20:34:11-05:00",
created_ms: 1403660051902,
profile_id: 232811,
channel_id: 2165604,
cube_url: "jondenver",
type: "profiles",
```

So if the activity type can be multiple things (IE Created Follow, Liked Event, Posted News, ETC) how would I go about putting this all in a sorted set?  I'm already sure I want the score to be the **created_ms** but the question is, can I do multiple values in a sorted set that all have keys as fields?  Should most of this be in a hash?  I realize this is a fairly open question but after trying to wrap my head around all the tutorials Im just concerned about setting up the data structure before had so I dont get caught to deep in the weeds.

Answer (score 2):

A sorted set is useful if you want to... keep stuff sorted! ;)

So, I assume you're interested in keeping the activities sorted by their creation time (ms). As for storing the actual data, you have two options:

1. Use the sorted set itself to store the data, even in native JSON format. Note that with this approach you'll only be able to fetch the entire JSON and you'll have to parse it at the client.
2. Alternatively, use the sorted to store "pointers" to hashes - i.e. the values will be key names in which you'll store the data. From your description, this appears the preferable approach.

Comment: Yeah I think the hard part is rapping my head around how to store all this stuff.  I agree that storing it all as json is probably not going ot be the more useful method so I'll be more then likely going with option 2.  As a visual learner its been hard to picture the set up in my head when im so used to creating index's etc in SQL.

Comment: That's exactly what the sorted set in #2 is all about - it's an index to your activities hashes.